# Signing transaction on frontend and sending on backend server

Tags: web3js, metamask, security, nodejs

Hi I'm making an NFT auction site similar to OpenSea to learn blockchain technology. But I have some security concerns about sending transactions on the frontend of my application because if a user decides to purchase an NFT and the transaction to transfer there funds is carried out on the frontend couldn't they just edit the javascript so they don't have to pay anything but the gas fee? If so how can i prevent this? Can this be prevented by signing the transaction on the frontend and then sending it on the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the transaction details you can sign them and use the signed data RLP encoding.
Once encoded, you can use the signed data and not concern if your user changes any value.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction

Hope this helps.

Comment: So i would have the user's Metamask account sign the transaction and then send the signed transaction to the server for the transaction to be sent? If so using web3 isn't the value of the transaction defined when you sign it and not send it so you could still edit the signing code on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the validation in the smart contract.

```
function buy(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
    require(msg.value == tokens[tokenId].price, "Not valid price");
}
```

The user could modify the transaction, but it will revert if the price isn't the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in such way.

- Initiate and create a transaction structure on the backend and send it to the frontend.
- On the frontend you can ask a user to sign an off-chain transaction, you will get a signature as an output. Check [EIP712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712).
- Send the signature of the transaction back to the backend.

**At this moment you would have the signature and tx data (that was generated by the backend).**

- Now you can recover the address from the signature and make sure that the user signed the exact transaction that was done on the backend side and it hasn't been changed.
- So now you can add some extra validations on the backend side and make sure that the backend has a valid transaction.
- Whenever you want to execute this transaction just send it from the backend to the frontend and ask the particular user to sign and execute the tx.

**Anyway, add all needed validations to the smart contracts**

I believe opensea does a similar thing. Basically, you can track all requests and responses that come between the frontend and the backend and look at what data comes from the backend and how frontend processes it.
Additionally check their new [seaport](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/seaport) protocol, you can see how they proccess and validate incoming data on behalf of smart contracts.

P.S. If you check seaport github, I recommend you go to the "reference" folder as all contracts are written directly on solidity there.